# Running 2 Gpio Events at the same time (ValueChanged)

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have a project which has encoders on both wheels of our robot (tries to count how many ticks, turns the wheel takes)
There is an event in Gpios the GpioName.ValueChanged that calls a function when a certain gpio changes its 'reading'/ value either from High to Low or vice versa. My problem is that I am not sure how my code doesn't work if I create 2 'event callers' such as..

TicksRightPin.ValueChanged += CountRight;
TicksLeftPin.ValueChanged += CountLeft;

but when I comment (not use the code) either one of them, the other line that is uncommented, works. Ex:

//TicksRightPin.ValueChanged += CountRight;
TicksLeftPin.ValueChanged += CountLeft;

or

TicksRightPin.ValueChanged += CountRight;
//TicksLeftPin.ValueChanged += CountLeft;

---

I want both of them to working..
here is my code. I hope I didn't make any confusions..

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ImageMap.Source = bp;
        DisableButtons();
        var gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();
        if (gpio == null)
        {
            CheckStatusText.Text = "There is no GPIO connected";
        }
        else
        {
            //Initializing all pins!!
            InitGpios();
            StartStop_Bool = false;
            RunBrake_Bool = false;
            CwCcw_Bool = true;
        }

        TicksRightPin.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        TicksLeftPin.DebounceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15);

        TicksRightPin.ValueChanged += CountRight;
        TicksLeftPin.ValueChanged += CountLeft;


    }


private async void CountLeft(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && Debouncing_Left == 0)
        {
            LeftMotor_TickCounter++;
            Debouncing_Left = 1;
            if (LeftMotor_TickCounter > 1 && CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
            {
                finalLeftCount++;
                LeftMotor_TickCounter = 0;
            }
            else if (LeftMotor_TickCounter > 1 && CwCcwPinLeft.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
            {
                finalLeftCount--;
                LeftMotor_TickCounter = 0;
            }
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
            {
                CounterLabelLeft.Text = Convert.ToString(finalLeftCount);
            });

        }
        if (TicksLeftPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low && Debouncing_Left == 1)
        {
            Debouncing_Left = 0;
        }


    }


private async void CountRight(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.High && Debouncing_Right == 0)
        {
            RightMotor_TickCounter++;
            Debouncing_Right = 1;
            if (RightMotor_TickCounter > 0 && CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.High)
            {
                finalRightCount++;
                RightMotor_TickCounter = 0;
            }
            if (RightMotor_TickCounter > 0 && CwCcwPinRight.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
            {
                finalRightCount--;
                RightMotor_TickCounter = 0;
            }

            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                CounterLabelRight.Text = Convert.ToString(finalRightCount);
            });


        }
        if (TicksRightPin.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low && Debouncing_Right == 1)
        {
            Debouncing_Right = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How and when did you change the value of the two pins(TicksRightPin&TicksLeftPin)?Have you debugged via setting breakpoints in the CountLeft and CountRight methods?Have you checked the voltage of the two pins?Please provide the more code(specially the InitGpios method) if possible.

Comment: the value of the pins changes when the sensor sets = 1, meaning when it senses a space in our 'encoder disk'. When using the digital tester to the out data of the encoders, it changes the voltage to 1.5v for logic = 1 (it's still theoretically considered as logic 1 in raspi)

Comment: What pins(left&right) did you use?